# Need elegant way to extract value as String from json maps in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am a JS newbie trying to extract some value from an array of json maps.
The map is something like:

```js
var  tags = [{
    Key: 'backup',
    Value: 'true'
  },
  {
    Key: 'Name',
    Value: 'sdlc-root'
  }
]

// Here is my first attempt:

var volName = tags.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Key === 'Name';
  })
  .map(result => {
    return result.Value;
  });
console.log(volName);
```

The result is:  `[ 'sdlc-root' ]`  , but I only need the String value.

The temporary solution I take for now is:

```
var volName = tags.filter(function(item) { return item.Key === 'Name'; })
                  .map(result => { return result.Value; })**[0]**;
console.log(volName);
```

The result is: `sdlc-root`

I hate my temporary solution, and would like to hear some advice for improvement or alternatives from experienced developers

Comment: do you have only one element inside?

Comment: Easy solution: destructure `var [volName] =` More elegant solution: use `.find`

Comment: @NinaScholz  I have multiple elements, above is just example, tks.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  not sure if my JS version support 'find', I think it's relatively new? Will definitely give a try. tks.

Comment: Don't let obsolete browsers cripple your ability to write concise, clean code - if an environment doesn't support ES6, use Babel + polyfills.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could find the element or a default object and take the wanted property.

```
var volName = (tags.find(({ Key }) => Key === 'Name') || {}).Value;
```

Comment: This is going to err if it doesn't find the correct value.

Comment: @chŝdk, you get from an empty object with a not given property the value `undefined`. this does not throw an error.

Comment: Why the ({Key})  - this seems easier to understand, no? `var volName = (tags.find(x => x.Key === "Name") || {}).Value` has less brackets

Comment: @mplungjan i think, if you need only a single property, you could destructure this property and show that you use only this property. it prevents as well an assignment to the object, if the value is a primitive value.

Answer (score 3):

Write a custom function like below

```js
var tags = [{
    Key: 'backup',
    Value: 'true'
  },
  {
    Key: 'Name',
    Value: 'sdlc-root'
  }
]

function f(tags) {
  for (i = 0; i <= tags.length; i++) {
    if (tags[i] && tags[i]['Key'] === 'Name') {
      return tags[i]['Value']
    }
  }
}

console.log(f(tags))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const tagsObj = tags.reduce((a, c) => { a[c.Key] = c.Value; return a }, {})
// {backup: "true", Name: "sdlc-root"}
console.log(tagsObj["Name"])
// "sdlc-root"
```